# Sudo not working for chmod

Tags: sudo, chmod

I am trying to install a piece of software on a clean AWS instance. It requires changing permissions on a bunch of files.

The first batch goes ok after

```
sudo chmod 644 config.local.php
sudo chmod -R 755 design images var
```

But when I try to run

```
sudo find design -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
```

I get

chmod: changing permissions of 'design/.htaccess': Operation not permitted

When I run 
    ls -l /usr/bin/sudo

I get root permissions of -rwsr-xr-x

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your command is not working because of the `|`, `xargs` is running as your regular user since it is working in another process than the one `find` is running.

`find` let you execute commands on files found, your command becomes:

```
`sudo find design -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`
```

P.S: Don't forget the <kbd>space</kbd> before `\;`.

Comment: Spectacular - that worked! Thanks so much pim!